# access the common methods from each objects by iterating through a list

Tags: c#, arrays, collections, interface, arraylist

I have multiple types of object instances that inherit from a common interface.
I would like to access the common methods from each objects by iterating through a list or arraylist or collections. how do I do that?

```
    {

    interface ICommon
    {
        string getName();
    }

    class Animal : ICommon
    {
        public string getName()
        {
            return myName;
        }
    }

    class Students : ICommon
    {
        public string getName()
        {
            return myName;
        }
    }

    class School : ICommon
    {
        public string getName()
        {
            return myName;
        }
    }


   }
```

When I add the animal, student, and School in an object[], and try to access
in a loop like

```
for (loop)
{
   object[n].getName // getName is not possible here. 
   //This is what I would like to have.
or 
   a = object[n];
   a.getName // this is also not working. 
}
```

is it possible to access the common method of different types in from a list or collections?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to either cast the object to `ICommon`

```
var a = (ICommon)object[n];
a.getName();
```

Or perferably you should use an array of `ICommon`

```
ICommon[] commonArray = new ICommon[5];
...
commonArray[0] = new Animal();
...
commonArray[0].getName();
```

Or you might want to consider using a `List<ICommon>`

```
List<ICommon> commonList = new List<ICommon>();
...
commonList.Add(new Animal());
...
commonList[0].getName();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use an "ICommon" array instead of using an "Object" array, otherwise when you retrieve the items of the "Object" array you will have to cast them.